# VueJS performance issues with a table loaded from an array

Tags: vuejs2

I have a performance problem with VueJS. I have a table with X rows, which I load through an array. The problem is that when I change a single element of the array, it renders all the array again, and therefore, performs all the conditions again (v-if, if inside v-bind:class, etc.). I leave a jsfiddle where from a table, hide only 1 element, and update the whole table again.

https://jsfiddle.net/toledorobia/0twghfya/

```
$(function(){
    var users = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        users.push({
            id: i,
            name: faker.name.findName(),
            email: faker.internet.email(),
            visible: true
        });
    }

    var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            users: users
        },
        methods: {
            random: function() {
                return faker.random.number();
            },
            toggleRows: function(){
                this.users[5].visible = !$(this.$refs.togglerows).is(":checked");
            }
        }
    });
});


<div id="app">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" ref="togglerows" v-on:click="toggleRows" /> Hide some rows
    </div>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="u in users" v-if="u.visible">
                <td>{{ u.id + ' ' + random() }}</td>
                <td>{{ u.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ u.email }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I avoid this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: sorry, I just updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because everything is rendered in the same scope, when you show/hide the single row you want, Vue is forced to re-render all the rows. Instead, isolate the scope of the changes using a component.

```
Vue.component("row",{
  props:["user"],
  template:`
    <tr>
      <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
      <td>{{random()}}</td>
      <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
    </tr>`,
  methods:{
    random: function() {
      return faker.random.number();
    },

  }
})
```

And your main template ends up looking like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr is="row" v-for="u in users" :key="u.id" v-if="u.visible" :user="u"></tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0twghfya/18/).